Pycharm multiple run tabs some detached
For Jetbrains PyCharm, sometimes I like to have multiple run tabs where one run tab is pinned, so I can monitor if it has exceptions and at the same time, I like to keep working on another project where I need to use the run window for a separate tab. When I run the script on the second project, it will have a separate tab next to the first one (that's pinned). How do I detach the second tab (two run windows floating), so I can move the first tab somewhere off-screen?
